# How to add a custom path to google maps and use it with directions api?

Tags: google-maps

I want to use the google maps javascript API for my project. I am using [directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) to show path between two places on the map. My problem is since this app is focusing on a very rural area all the paths in the area still not in the google maps. Can I include those new paths to my instance of google maps and use the directions API to navigate through the paths? How can I do this? Is there a way to add a path to map as a polyline and use it for directions?

Update:

here is a screenshot of the application I was developing.

[image]

The white color path, works with directions api. I draw a polygon with coordinates I know of the unknown path, I want to use that path with directions api to show directions.

Comment: You can use any valid coordinates to draw polylines, see this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

Comment: Thank you. That is the way to draw a polyline, but what I want to know is how to used this drawn path with the directions API. like a normal path in google maps?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I was actually gonna answer you re: directions but somehow forgot, give me a few minutes thanks!

Comment: Alright so, for directions API, you can use any valid lat/lng for both origin and destination (and any waypoints you may want to use) so provided that you know the coordinates of those rural locations, and that a route exists between these points, you can use the directions API and/or a polyline to compute a path between them.

Comment: You can play around this using the directions calculator https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: you mean I shoud at the every coordinates I know of the path I want to discribe to the waypoints array?

Comment: Sorry don't think I understood your question. I think it'll be easier if you can provide a detailed description of your use case and an actual example.

Comment: I will edit the question.

Comment: Sure! Will check it out later :)

Comment: evan I edited the question, can you help me out now?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the edit. So I can see that you're on the right track already. What you can do to compute directions for that rural location is to calculate the walking path between that point and the nearest point in road provided by the Directions API

Comment: @SankhaKarunasekara did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @KyleJoeckel unfortunately No.